# Hyperlink with a direct-download result

Tags: hyperlink, download

I've read a few threads on this but none of the answers seem to work.  I need to provide a link (i.e. say in a webpart being displayed in a page) that once the user clicks on that link, he/she will be prompted to download a file.  The file currently is located in the Documents library.

Adding "&download=1" or "?download=1" to the end of the link/url is not working

Answer (score 0):

Go to **web.config** file for the said web application and look for **downloadacopy.aspx** under the http handler section, note down this URL, generally when we click on the download file from document library this http handler is called internally.... use this URL as sample and construct the dynamic URL by passing the item id in the query string parameters.

Note :

- If you are working in SharePoint online, then we can't have the web.config file, in this case refer any web.config file from on-premise and use this as a sample... this technique is standard (out of the box) across the all environment of SharePoint.